# Cotton climbing pants with a zipper pocket (outdoor rock climbing use for small female climbers)

Tags: rock-climbing, climbing, sport-climbing

the "politicised" debate of female clothing not having pockets (it is especially about skirts and dresses) left aside, I wonder if there are any cotton climbing pants left on the market that have a zipper pocket. I like to use it for my phone or the topo (a map showing the climbing route) in shorter multi-pitch routes. My old ones are only made of wholes, but new ones are either of synthetic materials or do not have pockets.

Am I alone seeing this bad trend?

Comment: If the male range fit you, get one of theirs. I love my pockets and the pockets in the pockets. No idea why we women should do without.

Comment: The Black Diamond Notion Pants are cotton, and have four pockets, but the pockets aren't zipper.  Maybe you could mod one?